# Access a service in topnav with Authguard

Tags: angular, angular6

In my app I want to call a service in my top navigation, but my authguard keeps telling me I'm not logged in. I think it has something to do with my routing, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My App HTML:

```
<app-top-nav></app-top-nav>

<div id="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

TopNav Component:

```
export class TopNavComponent {
  myArray;
  someString;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService) {
    this.myArray = [];
    this.someString = '';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getSomeData();
  }

  getSomeData() {
    this.subscription = this.myService.get().subscribe(
      myArray => this.myArray = myArray
    );
  }
}
```

MyService.ts

```
interface PagedResult<T> {
  Items: T[];
  Count: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BedrijfService {
  private url = 'https://someurl.com/api';

  private myUrl = this.url + '/combos/Data2?UseAuthorization=false';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  get() {
    return this.httpClient.get<PagedResult<SomeData>>(this.url);
  }
}
```

This is my app.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'auth-callback',
    component: AuthCallbackComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'somepath',
    loadChildren: './somepath/somepath.module#SomepathModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

'SomePath' works as expected, I just don't know how to deal with the top nav component.

This is my AuthGuardservice:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    if (await this.authService.isLoggedInAsync()) {
      return true;
    }

    window.sessionStorage.setItem('portal_return_url', state.url);
    this.authService.startAuthentication();
    return false;
  }
}
```

The URL of my service in the top nav is called, however I keep getting an unauthorized error.

Comment: Please share the content of myservice as well. It's not possible to predict what is the body of `this.myService.get()` method

Comment: @Debojyoti I added the content of my service as well now

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getSomeData()
}
```

instead of `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: I actually tried that before, but I get exactly the same result. I thought maybe ngAfterViewInit would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, so I'll leave my solution here.
My service got loaded before the AuthGuard.

```
  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (await this.authService.isLoggedInAsync()) {
      this.getSomeData();
      return true;
    }
  }
```